# Nightwatch.js Global afterEach not working

Tags: nightwatch.js

I am trying to use the global hook afterEach to close the browser after each test, but once the first test completes it does not perform the global afterEach. Here is an example of my global.js, any help would be amazing!

```
module.exports = {
      afterEach: function (browser, done) {
        browser.end(function () {
          done();
        })
      },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[documentation](https://nightwatchjs.org/guide/using-nightwatch/external-globals.html#global-test-hooks) says it'll run after each **test suite**, not after each test, so that might be what you're experiencing :)